# Eclipse Mensagem: The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: java, eclipse

Montei um programinha em JAVA e quando fui executar apareceu esta mensagem, alguém sabe dizer por quê? Se alguém souber e poder me explicar fico muito agradecida :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, esse é meu código caso seja mais fácil entender o porque através do código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  

    public class Socio {

         int IdentSocio; 
         String NomeSocio, TelContato;
         double IdadeSocio;  

         //------- MÉTODO CONSTRUTOR -------//
         public Socio(){
             IdentSocio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o Código Identificador: "));
             NomeSocio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o Nome: ");
             IdadeSocio = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a idade: "));
             TelContato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o Telefone para Contato: ");
         }
    }
```

OUTRA CLASSE:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  

public class Atividades extends Socio{

    String Aparelho; 
    char Nivel;
    double Tempo;

    int cont;
    String Aparelho1, Aparelho2, Aparelho3;
    String Nivel1, Nivel2, Nivel3;
    String Tempo1, Tempo2, Tempo3;

    //---------- MÉTODO CONSTRUTOR ---------//
    public Atividades(int Quant){
        for(cont=1; cont <= Quant; cont++){

            if(cont == 1){
                Aparelho = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o aparelho: ");
                Aparelho1 = Aparelho;

                Nivel1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nível (A,B, ou C): ");
                //char[] Nivel = Nivel1.toCharArray(); //convertendo string para char

                Tempo = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o tempo: "));
                Tempo1 = Double.toString(Tempo); //convertendo double em string
            } 

            else
            if(cont == 2){
                Aparelho = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o aparelho: ");
                Aparelho2 = Aparelho;

                Nivel2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nível (A,B, ou C): ");
                //char[] Nivel = Nivel2.toCharArray(); //convertendo string para char

                Tempo = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o tempo: "));
                Tempo2 = Double.toString(Tempo); //convertendo double em string
            } 

            else
            if(cont == 3){
                Aparelho = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o aparelho: ");
                Aparelho3 = Aparelho;

                Nivel3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nível (A,B, ou C): ");
                //char[] Nivel = Nivel3.toCharArray(); //convertendo string para char

                Tempo = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o tempo: "));
                Tempo3 = Double.toString(Tempo); //convertendo double em string
            }
        }//for
    }//método construtor

    public void exibir(int Quant){
        for(int i=1; i <= Quant; i++){

            if(i == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Identificação do Sócio: " + IdentSocio + "\nNome do Sócio: " + NomeSocio + "\nTelefone: " + TelContato + "\nIdade: " + IdadeSocio + "\n\nAparelho: " + Aparelho1 + "\nNível: " + Nivel1 + "\nTempo: " +  Tempo1,"VISUALIZAÇÃO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            if(i == 2){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Identificação do Sócio: " + IdentSocio + "\nNome do Sócio: " + NomeSocio + "\nTelefone: " + TelContato + "\nIdade: " + IdadeSocio + "\n\nAparelho: " + Aparelho2 + "\nNível: " + Nivel2 + "\nTempo: " +  Tempo2,"VISUALIZAÇÃO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            if(i == 3){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Identificação do Sócio: " + IdentSocio + "\nNome do Sócio: " + NomeSocio + "\nTelefone: " + TelContato + "\nIdade: " + IdadeSocio + "\n\nAparelho: " + Aparelho3 + "\nNível: " + Nivel3 + "\nTempo: " +  Tempo3,"VISUALIZAÇÃO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }//for
    }//método exibir
    public static void main(){
        String Resp="";

        do{  

            //Socio obj1 = new Socio(); //instancia método

            String Quants = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a quantidade de Aparelhos (de 1 a 3): ");
            int Quant = Integer.parseInt(Quants);

            Atividades obj2 = new Atividades(Quant); //instancia método
                obj2.exibir(Quant);

            Resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar? sim ou não. ");

            if(Resp.equals("NÃO") || Resp.equals("não") || Resp.equals("NAO") || Resp.equals("nao"))
                break;

        } while(!Resp.equals("NÃO") || !Resp.equals("não") || !Resp.equals("NAO") || !Resp.equals("nao"));

        System.exit(0); 
    }//main
}//classe Atividades
```

Comment: A assinatura do seu método `main` está errada.

Comment: ah é verdade ñ acredito!

Comment: uhu kkk funcionou agora, obrigada @BrunoCésar

Comment: quer escrever a resposta ai pra mim marcar como certa: ` public static void main(String args[])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é devido a assinatura do método principal estar errada, veja:

```
public static void main()
```

Basta ajustar, fornecendo uma assinatura conforme previsto na [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4), ou seja, isso:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
```

Ou isso:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
```

Já trecho `and there are no recent launches.` é devido a você não ter executado nada antes ;)